# Trabalhando com 3 modelos dentro de um formulário cakephp 2x

Tags: php, cakephp

Estou penando para fazer isso ,as como que trabalho com 3 modelos dentro de um formulário, sendo que o formulário é referente ao modelo principal e os outros 2 modelos são associados a esse modelo.

Exemplo:
`<?php echo $this->Form->create('Escola', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('nome', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('descricao', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('EscolaTeste.nome', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('EscolaTeste.desc', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('EscolaNova.nome', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('EscolaNova.desc', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>`

E na hora de salvar eu uso `saveAll`, lembrando que `Escola` é o modelo principal e `EscolaTeste` e `EscolaNova` são  `hasMany` de `Escola`

Comment: E o que está acontecendo?

Comment: Resolvi, esqueci que modelos em `hasMany` são tratados como array, então os modelos associais tem que ter o nome dessa forma `modeloAssiado.0.field`